# providing special effect to view of android screen

Tags: android, animation

I would like provide and animation effect but i don't how to do. Even i don't know what type of effect it should be called so that i can search on Google.

So my problem is ..

when user click a button a view or a layout should be display. i want to give effect to that view like ... it should be look like that that view is coming from left side of screen to right side and finally it should display my view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modification like you want:

```
Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
animation.setDuration(1000);
animation.setStartOffset(0);
set.addAnimation(animation);

animation = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
        0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);
animation.setDuration(1000);
set.addAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: yahh .. i got it .. thnks for ur reply ...

Answer (score 0):

```
public static android.view.animation.Animation in;
in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx, R.anim.slide_in);
view.startAnimation(in);
```

you may define the animation in a seperat xml like:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
<translate 
    android:fromXDelta="100%p" 
    android:toXDelta="0" 
    android:duration="300" />
<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="0.0" 
    android:toAlpha="1.0" 
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:duration="300" />
```

edit: here a animation from left to right, play a bit around:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"      android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
<translate 
android:fromXDelta="-100%p" 
android:toXDelta="0" 
android:duration="150" />
```

Comment: hey budy ... thnks for your quick reply ... i have try to implement with pure java code ... i m getting little animation which is displaying my linear layout from top to bottom ... i want it to come from left to right ... i m spotin code below please see

Comment: try to understand the concept, maby by following the postet link, then you are able to wirite every animation you want by yourself, i give you the piece you need by editing my post

Comment: is there any good tutorial or ebook for understanding animation ..

Comment: except android developer site ... if you having any idea .. please give me some link or name of ebook or link to some good articles

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the API demos in the Android sdk. There are a few animations demo (in Views > Animations).

Answer (score 0):

AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);

```
    Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    animation.setDuration(1000);
    animation.setStartOffset(0);
    set.addAnimation(animation);

    animation = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            -1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);
    animation.setDuration(1000);
    set.addAnimation(animation);
```